# How to find element by attribute value in GPath?

Tags: java, xpath, groovy, gpath

What is an alternative to this XPath `//div[@id='foo']` in GPath? In general, where I can find this documentation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is the corresponding snippet:

```
def node = new XmlSlurper().parseText(...)
def foo = node.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'div' && it.@id == 'foo'}
```

A few other links you may want to read:

- [GPath documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath)
- [Processing XML with Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)

Comment: It's Groovy, not GPath. I need a single GPath expression.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, since GPath is mostly using groovy syntax with the following extra symbols:

    ".." that returns the parent
    "*" that returns all the children
    "**" that act as a depth first loop
    "@" that is used to access a property the normal node accessor.

Answer (score 9):

The previous poster gave you all that's required: Assuming your document has been slurped into `xml`, you want

```
def foo = xml.path.to.div.find{it.@id == 'foo'}
```

to find a single result. Or `findAll` to find all results.

Comment: `//` in XPath means that I don't know the exact path to `div`

Comment: ok. then the previous poster gave you the solution: - use `xml.depthFirst().find{it.name() == 'div' && id.@id == 'foo}`

Comment: @winstaan74 What's the expression for getting all elements with a specific attribute name?

Comment: `xml.'**'.findAll { it.@attributeName }`

Answer (score 3):

To mimic the expression //div[@id='foo'] the closest thing you can do with a GPath is:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
xml.'**'.div.findAll { it.@id=="foo" }
```

the '**' is pretty much the same as '//' in your XPath.

```
xml.'**'.div
```

will yield all the nodes of type div at any level.

Later filtering with findAll() with the given closure you get a list of nodes as you do in the XPath case

Answer (score 1):

what you need is this:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(<locOfXmlFileYouAreParsing>.toURL().text)

def foundNode = root.'**'.find{ it.@id == "foo" }
```

its the double * that will let you find it without knowing the path. At least this is how I do it.

Comment: How do you find the first instance of a node by element name, assuming there's more than one?

Comment: `xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'elementName' }`

And that will be the first one.